# Não consigo capturar regex do fim da string com o método replace do Java

Tags: java, regex

Tentei esse código mas o `$` não é entendido como final da string e sim como caractere a ser capturado mesmo, **fiz algo errado ou é um bug**?

```
String s = "gabriel";
System.out.println(s.replace("iel$", ""));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-), o método `replace` **não** funciona com expressões regulares.

O que você quer é o [método `replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). Esse sim trabalha com regex:

```
String s = "gabriel";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("iel$", "")); // gabr
```

---

Se bem que **nesse caso específico** não precisa de regex:

```
String s = "gabriel";
System.out.println(s.replace("iel", ""));
```

Comment: MEU HERÓI VLWWW